# EF Core Entity Equality

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Sorry if this is a dumb question, most of my experience with ORMs has not been EF, and looking this up online gets me a *lot* of bad hits.  It's almost like "reference" means different things to different people...

If I write code like so:

```
using (var db = new DbContext())
{
    var entity1 = await db.Foos.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 1);
    var entity2 = await db.Foos.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == 1);
    return entity1.Equals(entity2);
}
```

This returns `true`. Since my entity is a reference type, the `Equals` under the hood should be an `Object.ReferenceEquals()` call.

What I want to know is, is this reliable, i.e. will any entity represented by a particular database record in a context always be referentially equal, or can it "drop out" of the cache, get reloaded on demand and have a new reference like what happens in some less sophisticated ORMs?  If an entity is loaded as part of a collection on another entity, is it still the same object?  Are there rules/ settings that govern this behavior?

Comment: When you use `Find`, then 3 things happen, in order of priority: 1) EF looks for object in local cache, 2) EF looks for in added objects, 3) EF loads data from database.

Comment: Unless this is documented behaviour (and I don't think it is), _I_ wouldn't rely on it. And someone could always override `Equals`...

Comment: @JohnyL I figured it would be something like that, but how robust is the local cache?  Is it something that will definitely last for the lifetime of the database context, does it stick around till it needs the space, or until it feels the record is stale?  I'm trying to find out how reliable it is if I care about uniqueness.

Comment: Except for [Non-Tracking Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556203(v=vs.113).aspx), it's guaranteed (although I can't find documentation). In fact it's a source of many issues receiving "another entity with the same key is already tracked by the context" exceptions. Also EF really enforces reference equality for tracking, so even if the objects override `Equals`, they still detect the equal references and not custom equality. Or taking your example, they internally always use `ReferenceEquals(entity1, entity2)` rather than `entity1.Equals(entity2)`.

Comment: I've missed the EF Core tag. All I wrote in the previous comments still applies. It's sort of explained in [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/overview) and [Tracking vs. No-Tracking Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) - note the word **identity** in *No tracking queries still perform identity resolution within the excuting query.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @IvanStoev pointed out in the comments, the referential consistency is by design and a core part of EF, so the same object in the database should always reference the same object in the database context... at least in the scope of the specific database context you're in.  YMMV if you are dealing with multiple database contexts.